# How to convert a binary string into bipolar representation in python?

Tags: python, binary

Presently I have a binary number of the format '0b10100'. To be used in a binarised neural network, I would like to convert the binary number into bipolar, i.e., replacing 0s with -1s therefore giving a representation like '1 -1 1 -1 -1'. Is there any default method in python to do that? And also in which format I can get the output?

Comment: I dont know it there is a method specifically for that but what you can do it replace 0 with -1 like `binarystring.replace('0','-1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip off the leading text ("0b") using slice notation:

```
s = "0b10100"
s[2:]           # "10100"
```

You can convert the resulting string to a list of characters by taking advantage of the fact that strings are iterable, and the `list()` builtin accepts an iterable:

```
list(s[2:])    # [ '1', '0', '1', '0', '0' ]
```

You can convert the individual 1-character strings into integers with the `int()` builtin. A *list comprehension* allows you to express this in line:

```
newlist = [int(ch) for ch in list(s[2:])]
                # [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

You can observe that 0/1 can be converted to -1/1 by doubling the input and subtracting one:

```
newlist = [2 * int(ch) - 1 for ch in list(s[2:])]
                # [1, -1, 1, -1, -1]
```